# Sorting items that have the same value in LinkedList??? - java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

i have a problem while i am trying to sort my LinkedList.
I used the following code:

```
Collections.sort(mylist, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                int one= Integer.parseInt(o1[1]);
                int two = Integer.parseInt(o2[1]);
                return one-two;
            }
        });
```

Here i put some values:

```
    thelist.testing("a",1);
    thelist.testing("b",5);
    thelist.testing("c",5);
    thelist.testing("d",5);
    thelist.testing("e",7);
    System.out.println(thelist);
```

I have these results : a:1,b:5,c:5,d:5,e:7

I want the ouput to be like this when items have the same number :a:1,d:5,c:5,b:5,e:7

Comment: I think it would be better to create an object then to use arrays.

Comment: Why do you want that output? do you want your input having the same value to just come in reverse order of insertion?

Comment: yes exactly Rohit Jain

Comment: I agree with @BheshGurung , unless you posted a simplified example and forgot to explain the generic cases.
If you want to sort by multiple criteria, then you should sort by the least important criterion first, and the most important criterion last.

Comment: how i can do the thing that @RohitJain said ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
Collections.sort(mylist, new Comparator<String[]>() {  
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {  
                if(o1[1].equals(o2[1]){  
                   return -(o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]));
                }  

                int one= Integer.parseInt(o1[1]);
                int two = Integer.parseInt(o2[1]);
                return one-two;
            }
        });
```

Example code:

```
List<String[]> mylist = new ArrayList<String[]>();  
mylist.add(new String[]{"a","1"});  
mylist.add(new String[]{"b","5"});  
mylist.add(new String[]{"c","5"});  
mylist.add(new String[]{"d","5"});  
mylist.add(new String[]{"e","7"});
```

Output:

```
[a, 1]  
[d, 5]  
[c, 5]  
[b, 5]   
[e, 7]
```

Comment: shouldn't `if(o1[1] == o2[1]){` be `if(o1[1].equals(o2[1])){` ?

Comment: it's not working. i want to print out the items that i add in main in reverse order. not by alphabetically

Comment: Maybe you should add a number indicating your insertion order to each item in your linked list. That way the information is preserved, even after multiple manipulations of the list.

Comment: @jlordo:Yes.I was thinking of chars originally.Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

If you want the most recently added first, reverse the list before sorting it. The Java List sort is stable, preserving the order of equal items. You should aim to have the equal value items in the target order before sorting.